# UITabBar Action in a loop

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I have created a view loading to it toolbar with few 7 buttons.
I want to add action for each - thus each one will perform different action all of them will load view but according to the user selection of the button I will load to the view different screen i.e buttons etc..

Here is my loop:

```
int i =0;

    for (NSString *items in array)
    {
        //Set button style
        [barButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];

        //Set the button title
        [barButton setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:i]];


        [barButton setAction:@selector(tmp:)];

        //Add the bar button to the array - later will load the array to the tool bar items list.
        [itemsArray insertObject:barButton atIndex:i];

        i++;


    }
```

As you see setAction is now activate tmp method - I want to take it from the name of the method from the NSString value of the array - ideas?

Comment: try to accept an answer if it is what you need. Or ask for some precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSSelectorFromString` function. See here :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString